# auto invoke a javascript function from the child view, after jquery ready, in _layout view, when page loads

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor, jquery-plugins

**strong text**In my ASP MVC 5 app, I have a (master - **Jquery loads here**) `_layout.cshtml`  and (child, my **function sortable here, not loading**) views `tableView.cshtml`

In the *child* tableView.cshtml, I've written custom JS functions that need to be invoked on Jquery Read $ ready. Since jquery has already loaded in the master page, **how can I attach my function (and 3rd parts plugins) invoke it when my child page loads?**

if possible, please share a modular way to attach and initialize my functions and 3rd party plugins in the childviews on the child view loading/navigation load, **so that when the main jquery function loads, it also invokes my functions.**

**_layout.cshtml**

```
//  DOM ready is completed in master layout, I have custom JS plugin/code (sortable)
// in the child view that I need to load, when that loads

   $( document ).ready(function() {
      console.log( "Master layout ready, done" );
      });
```

**TableView.cshtml**

```
// in my tableView, that inherits layout from master, 
// how can I get this loaded when the page loads

  (function() {
    console.log( "How can I get child table plugin, loaded!" );
    })();
```

Comment: By child view do you mean partial views loaded using `@Html.Partial` or `@Html.Action` or a view that uses the layout

Comment: @StephenMuecke I don't mean partial view, just a regular view, that uses master layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make use of `@RenderSection()` which act as placeholders to render content from the view

You layout page might look something like

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  .....
  // Include common style sheets here
  @RenderSection("styles", false) // placeholder for styles
  @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>
<body>
  ....
  @RenderBody()
  ....
  // Include all common scripts here
  @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery") // include jquery first
  @RenderSection("scripts", required: false) // placeholder for page specific scripts
</body>
</html>
```

and in the view

```
@model YourModel
// html here
....
@section styles {
  <link href="~/Content/PageSpecificStyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" />
}
@section scripts {
  // Add page specific scripts and plugin files here
  @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
  <script src="../../Scripts/MyScript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  ....
  <script type="text/javascript">
    // Other javascript code here
  </script>
}
```

Note `@RenderSection("styles", false)` is in the `<head>` element and `@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)` is immediately before the closing `</body>` tag meaning any scripts defined in the view will be loaded after the page elements have loaded (and after the jquery file)

Comment: How do I ensure my script is invoked, in the second scenario, before the closing. `(function () {
        $('.table').table_struct({
            'add_option': true,                        
        });
    })();`  Does this get loaded auto - with/will the self executing closing paren invoke it? or should i move the script to a separate js file and call and an init function from there. What pattern can i use to ensure it gets loaded.

Comment: Your could just add `$('.table').table_struct({ 'add_option': true, });` where I indicated _// Other javascript code here_ (so long as the plugin with the `table_struct` function is loaded after jquery and before this code). At this point the DOM has been loaded and your elements with `class="table"` now exist (but you can always put it in an external file if you want)